# Matplotlib: changing font size of exponent

Tags: matplotlib

I want to change the fontsize of the exponent as marked on the picture [image: pic]
I cannot use the matplotlib.rc('font', **font) method since I have different plots that need different font sizes so I change every element individually. I can however not find the font properties of the exponent.

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the exponent in the first place by dividing the data by 1e12 and noting that on the label?

Comment: Do you change the fontsize of the labels anywhere? The labels of the y-axes seem larger than those of the x-axis. You can perhaps use something like [tick_params](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

Comment: @Robbert: yes I changed all the other fonts, just can't find out how to do it for the exponent.

Comment: @tiago: Maybe an option, but then I need to calculate the exponent that fit's best myself.

Comment: is the exponent an `offsetText`? If not, how is computed?

Comment: Is it a coincident that the exponent seems to have the same fontsize as the legend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the exponent is an `offset` computed by `matplotlib` you can do the following to change the font size of the exponent to `30`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,1.0001,100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x)
t = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
t.set_size(30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: For the record, this also works if the exponent is a multiplier too